# Validação ao editar cadastro existente?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um seguinte problema: estou mexendo na parte de `controller` do meu sistema na parte de editar cadastros e ele faz a seguinte verificação, se eu digito um código já existente, ele exibe um ***alerta***.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserNotFound", 
                         "Este Paciente já está cadastrado!: ");
```

E queria que na hora de exibir o alerta ele informar qual o **ID do paciente** que foi cadastrado com aquele dado que fiz a seguinte alteração.

```
ModelState.AddModelError("UserNotFound",
                         "Este Paciente já está cadastrado!: " + obj.CadastroId);
```

Só que quando eu uso o `obj.CadastroId` ele está exibindo o **ID do paciente** que estou editando. Resumindo, quando aparecer o alerta, exibir o **ID do paciente** que já foi cadastrado com aquele dado.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?, deixei nesse link o método que estou usando no `controller`.

**Repository:**

```
public bool pacienteExiste(string numero_protuario)  
{  
    Cadastro cadastro = Db.Cadastros
         .FirstOrDefault(c => c.pront == numero_protuario);  
    return cadastro != null;  
}
```

---

**Service:**

```
public bool pacienteExiste(string numero_protuario)
{
    return _cadastroRepository.pacienteExiste(numero_protuario);
}
```

---

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult EditarCadastro(Cadastro obj)  
{  
    if (_cadastroService.pacienteExiste(obj.pront))  
    {  
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserNotFound", 
                "Este Paciente já está cadastrado!: " + obj.CadastroId);  
        return View(obj);  
    }  
    if ((obj.pront != null) || (obj.inpac != null) || (obj.dtnasc != null))  
    {  
        _cadastroService.Update(obj);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cadastro");  
    }  
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cadastro");  
}
```

Comment: Por que não posta o código direto aqui? Aliás, coloque também o código do método `_cadastroService.pacienteExiste`

Comment: @jbueno public bool pacienteExiste(string numero_protuario)
        {
            Cadastro cadastro = Db.Cadastros.FirstOrDefault(c => c.pront == numero_protuario);
            return cadastro != null;
        }

Comment: Cliente em [edit] e coloque o código na pergunta.

Comment: @jbueno coloquei lá, mais não sei editar pra deixar visivel

Comment: Seleciona o código e clica ctrl + k

Comment: @jbueno Pronto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só é necessário buscar esse registro no banco pra retornar as informações dele.

Aproveite o método que busca o registro pra fazer a validação, removendo a necessidade de usar **`_cadastroService.pacienteExiste(obj.pront)`**. Assim a consulta só precisa ser feita uma vez no banco.

Aliás, percebi que um `service` fazendo um meio termo (pra que tudo isso???) então vou seguir o seu padrão.

**Repository:**

```
public Cadastro BuscaPacientePeloProtuario(string numero_protuario)
{
    return Db.Cadastros.FirstOrDefault(c => c.pront == numero_protuario);  
}
```

**Service:**

```
public Cadastro BuscaPacientePeloProtuario(string numero_protuario)
{
    return _cadastroRepository.BuscaPacientePeloProtuario(numero_protuario);
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult EditarCadastro(Cadastro obj)  
{  
    var existente = _cadastroService.BuscaPacientePeloProtuario(obj.pront);

    if (existente != null)
    {             
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserNotFound", "Este Paciente já está cadastrado!: " + existente.CadastroId);

        return View(obj);  
    }  

    if ((obj.pront != null) || (obj.inpac != null) || (obj.dtnasc != null))  
    {  
        _cadastroService.Update(obj);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cadastro");  
    }  

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cadastro");  
}
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54616/discussion-on-answer-by-jbueno-validacao-ao-editar-cadastro-existente)

Answer (score 0):

Pensando em um código mais elegante eu recomendaria a você utilizar o conceito  [Tell Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)

Ta, mas o que isso ajudar em seu problema?
Ao melhorar o designe você pode retornar o erro encapsulando a lógica de validação do seu usuário.
Veja um exemplo abaixo de como poderia ser escrito seu código, apenas adapte a sua estrutura, nomes de variáveis e padrões:

```
 enum Status
{
    Sucesso,
    Falha
}

interface IErros
{
    void AdicionarErro(IErros erro);
}

interface IResultado
{
    Status Status { get; }
    IErros Erros { get; }
}

class Falha : IResultado
{
    public IErros Erros { get; private set; }

    public Status Status { get { return Status.Falha; } }

    public IResultado AdicionarErro(string mensagem)
    {
        // adiciona o erro
        return this;
    }
}

class Sucesso : IResultado
{
    public IErros Erros { get; private set; }

    public Status Status { get { return Status.Sucesso; } }
}

class Cadastro
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NumeroProntuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
}

class Db
{
    public static IEnumerable<Cadastro> Cadastros { get; set; }
}

class CadastroService
{
    public IResultado SalvarPaciente(Cadastro dadosCadastrais)
    {
        Cadastro cadastro = Db.Cadastros
             .FirstOrDefault(c => c.NumeroProntuario == dadosCadastrais.NumeroProntuario);
        if (cadastro != null)
            return new Falha().AdicionarErro("Já foi cadastrado um paciente com os mesmos dados cadastrais, Id: " + cadastro.Id);
        return new Sucesso();
    }
}
```

Fiz um pequeno mock para db para não ter que gerar a classe e o contexto do EF.
Mas note, que ao invés de retornar um bool, você encapsula a lógica do seu erro e tira a responsabilidade da web e pode acessar na sua controller da seguinte maneira:

```
    public IActionResult EditarCadastro(Cadastro obj)
    {
        var resultado = _cadastroService.SalvarPaciente(obj);
        if (resultado.Status == Status.Falha)
            ModelState.AddModelError(resultado.Erros.First());

        // faz o restando da lógica
    }
```

Com isso obtemos um design melhor elaborado e toda a complexidade das validações encapsuladas no serviço.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao SO-pt! Recomendo a leitura sobre [como escrever uma boa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).